# Search and replace text and everything that follows in the same line

Tags: linux, find-and-replace

How can I search for a certain string in multiple files (with a given extension) in a directory and replace everything afterwards (including the search string) with a blank string?

---

#### Example

I'm searching for 'mystring'

File contains:

```
foo bar mystring bar foo
```

I'm trying to get to:

```
foo bar
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [recursively replace every instance of a word in a directory from linux command line](http://superuser.com/questions/162133/recursively-replace-every-instance-of-a-word-in-a-directory-from-linux-command-l)

Comment: or this http://superuser.com/questions/162133/recursively-replace-every-instance-of-a-word-in-a-directory-from-linux-command-l?rq=1

Comment: *> and replace everything afterwards (including the search string) with a blank string* … what do you mean by afterwards? Everything following in that line?

Comment: @Dennis Looks like I may have misunderstood the requirement here, so lets wait and see what the OP says

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -i "s/mystring.*//" <filename>
```

-i does the replacing inline (i.e. infile == outfile). Without -i the result of the replacing would be printed to stdout.

Comment: @Dan: To do this in a `.txt` files (for example), replace `<filename>` by `*.txt`. Bash does the rest.

Comment: +1 for sed because it should already be installed.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to work on files in subdirectories recursively,

```
perl -p -i -e 's/mystring.*//' *.ext
```